# JSTL - Using forEach to iterate over a user-defined class

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, iteration, jsp-tags

What methods do I need to add to a custom Java class so that I can iterate over the items in one of its members? I couldn't find any specifications about how the JSTL forEach tag actually works so I'm not sure how to implement this.

For example, if I made a generic "ProjectSet" class and I woud like to use the following markup in the JSP view:

```
<c:forEach items="${projectset}" var="project">
...
</c:forEach>
```

Basic class file:

```
public class ProjectSet {
    private ArrayList<Project> projects;
    public ProjectSet() {
        this.projects = new ArrayList<Project>();
    }
    // .. iteration methods ??
}
```

Is there any interface that I must implement like PHP's `ArrayAccess` or `Iterator` in order for this to work?

Edit: Without directly accessing the ArrayList itself, because I will likely be using some sort of Set class using generics, and the JSP view shouldn't have to know about the inner workings of the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Iterable interface provides this functionality:

```
public class ProjectSet implements Iterable<Project> {
    private ArrayList<Project> projects;
    public ProjectSet() {
        this.projects = new ArrayList<Project>();
    }

    // .. iteration methods ??
   @Override
   public Iterator<Project> iterator() {
       return projects.iterator();
   }
}
```

You can exchange the iterator logic as you need.

Comment: Caveat to that is that JSTL forEach does not support iterable (extremely annoying) as forEach type. So you need to do ${projectSet.iterator()}

Comment: Actually .iterator() will only work on the latest Servlet Container (and even the latest JSTL still does not support iterable). You will need to make a getter for the iterator ( getIterator() ).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should implement [java.util.Iterable](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `forEach` tag does not support `Iterable` as the items source. It does support:

- Arrays
- `Collection`
- `Iterator`
- `Enumeration`
- `Map`
- Comma-separated list of values given in a `String`

(relevant source code: [ForEachSupport](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.glassfish.web/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/1.2.3/source-code/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/ForEachSupport.java))

Of these, it's probably best to use an `Iterator` as the `forEach` source when you wish to fetch items from your own class.